# Interact with unity UI elements (canvas) in Cardboard VR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I am using the google Cardboard VR plug in unity to create a vr application.
In google cardboard VR, how do I interact with the UI elements such as Button, scroll, select etc of unity UI components? The reticle now works on the objects which are in a specified layer (in my case "Interactable" by following the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart) ) but those are more like physical objects. I want to click and drag on UI elements in VR using the reticle.

I tried to put the canvas in the world space and put it on the specified layer, but the reticle doesn't seem to detect it as a interactable object. Probably becasue it uses a physics raycast and my UI canvas is not a physics object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.